# Routes don't have access to store given in Provider Redux React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I would like my components to mostly have access to the store via their props.

I believe the correct way to do this when using `redux` is by using `connect` on the `Provider`

I have all of this set up, but still my `Components` do not have state as a `prop`

**App.js**

I have added everything here for completeness as I believe I am stupid , I am sorry.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as currentSexActionCreator from '../actions/currentSexActionCreator';

import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(nextValue) {
        browserHistory.push(`/${nextValue}`)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

App.propTypes = {
    // Injected by React Router
    children: PropTypes.node
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        errorMessage: state.errorMessage,
        inputValue: ownProps.location.pathname.substring(1),
        'hutber':'hutber'
    }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        currentSexAction: bindActionCreators(currentSexActionCreator, dispatch)
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

**A Component - That should have props**

```
class Sex extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            participants: 1
        }
    }

    onSetParticipants = (data) => {
        store.dispatch (currentSex.setParticipants(data.valueText)); //the incorrect way to dispatch things, store is referencing the store
    }

    render() {
        console.info(this.props);
        return (
            <div>
                ....
                something here
                ....
            </div>
        )
    }
}    

export default Sex;
```

*The provider**

```
export default class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    const { store, history } = this.props;
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
          <Router history={history}>
            <Route path="/" component={App}>
              <IndexRoute component={Splash}/>

              {/*No Signed In Page*/}
              <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} onEnter={authStates.blockForLoggedInUsers}/>
              <Route path="/signup" component={signUp} onEnter={authStates.blockForLoggedInUsers}/>
              <Route path="/signupconfirm" component={SignUpConfirm} onEnter={authStates.blockForLoggedInUsers}/>

              {/*Login Required*/}
              <Route path="/home" component={Home} onEnter={authStates.requireLogin}/>
              <Route path="/selection" component={Selection} onEnter={authStates.requireLogin}/>

              {/*Sex Selection*/}
              <route path="/desire" component={Desire} onEnter={authStates.requireLogin}/>
              <route path="/desire/saved" component={DesireSaved} onEnter={authStates.requireLogin}/>
              <route path="/masturbation" component={Masturbation} onEnter={authStates.requireLogin}/>
              <route path="/masturbation/saved" component={MasturbationSaved} onEnter={authStates.requireLogin}/>
              <route path="/sex" component={Sex} onEnter={authStates.requireLogin}/>
              <route path="/sex/saved" component={SexSaved} onEnter={authStates.requireLogin}/>

            </Route>
          </Router>
          {/*<DevTools />*/}
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

I am unsure if you need more information, but basically inside my component `console.info(this.props.store)` is `undefined`

Maybe I am not thinking about it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

`connect` doesn't magically populate props for child components of the connected one. It only passes store variables as props to the one you connect. If you want to pass them down further you must do so yourself:

```
let App = ({ foo }) => {
  return React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { foo, somethingElse: 'blah' })
}

connect(state => ({ foo: state.foo }))(App)
```

If this makes sense for you, go for it, however it's probably more common to connect the component (or container, if you will) that is expecting the store data. There's nothing wrong with connecting hundreds of components.

```
class Sex extends Component {
  // now you have access to store data and dispatch
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Sex)
```

Comment: Every component that uses a part of the state should use its *own* `connect` call. Even though you could manually pass props down from the `App`, you shouldn't do that. Using `connect` on each component that uses the data directly is much more performant because React-Redux makes sure only changed components get rerendered. This isn't possible if you pass all props down from above. If you do that then the entire app will be rerendered each time even a tiny change happens in the app. Without Redux you'd need to use `shouldComponentUpdate` to keep your app performant. `connect` takes over this j

Comment: I think we agree on that then. Keep in mind though, a lot literature about Redux is about smart and dumb components, where passing down props to dumb components is pretty much the norm. I think it's always best to use judgement in your own app to strike the right balance.

Comment: Yes, I agree with this answer but wanted to elaborate and clarify. A "smart" component wrapping a "dumb" component is very light and it's fine to render both the "smart" and "dumb" component, but it's not fine to render the entire app on any small change.

Comment: Would it be too much to ask for an answer @DDS? But I'm correct, each component should have its own `mapStateToProps` and likewise export its own `connect`?

Comment: Aht that is what you've said @azium Sorry I missed this. I will try this now. Lastly then, how to you reference the state in your component? `store.getState()`?

Comment: You don't touch state in your component. You leave this task up to `mapStateToProps`. The component only touches props. The store should never be passed as a prop. Neither should `getState`.